# Swing timers basic functionality

Tags: java, swing, timer, jframe, awt

I'm new at java graphic design, and I would like you, if possible, to help me with an easy example to help me to get to understand the basic functionality of JFrames, Timers, SwingControllers, and all this stuff. How would you implement the following case:

We have a JFrame with a JPanel inside.
When the execution starts, the JPanel is white, but we want it to change it's colour every two seconds:

```
public class MiJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public MiJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new MiJFrame().setVisible(true);
                jPanel1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
                jPanel1.setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private static javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

At first, I used the sleep method of a thread object between the setBackgroud() methods but it doesn't work, as it only shows the last change. How would you use here a Timer object?

Comment: *"How would you use here a Timer object?"* If I was at the stage of asking that question, I'd be checking out the [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) tutorial.

Comment: `extends javax.swing.JFrame`  Don't extend GUI components if not necessary.  Simply keep a reference to the frame (assuming you need a ref. to it).

Comment: As it goes to `setBackground()` method it does work you just need to call `repaint()` after you make the changes. But for this use the Swing's Timer you are right, just read the link @AndrewThompson provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, whenever you need to change the colour of the said thingy, always set `Opaque` property to true for the said thingy. Like in your case it's the `JPanel` so first of all you must use `panelObject.setOpaque(true)`, for some `Look And Feel`s calling this method is a must for background colour changes to take effect.

Do try this code example, regarding the rest :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
/*
 * @see
 * http://stackoverflow.com/q/11036830/1057230
 */

public class ColourTimer
{
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private Timer timer;
    private int counter;
    private Color[] colours = {
                                Color.RED,
                                Color.WHITE,
                                Color.BLUE,
                                Color.DARK_GRAY,
                                Color.YELLOW,
                                Color.LIGHT_GRAY,
                                Color.BLACK,
                                Color.MAGENTA,
                                Color.PINK,
                                Color.CYAN
                              };

    private ActionListener timerAction = new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            if (counter == (colours.length - 1))
                counter = 0;
            contentPane.setBackground(colours[counter++]);
        }    
    };

    public ColourTimer()
    {
        counter = 0;
    }

    private void displayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Colour Timer");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setOpaque(true);

        final JButton button = new JButton("STOP");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                if (timer.isRunning())
                {
                    button.setText("START");
                    timer.stop();
                }
                else
                {
                    button.setText("STOP");
                    timer.start();
                }
            }
        });

        frame.getContentPane().add(contentPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        timer = new Timer(2000, timerAction);
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new ColourTimer().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right it it good approach to remember to `setOpaque(true)` for a 'thingy', but in this case a `JPanel` has it 'true' by defaultm thus it is not the case here. Other then that nice code sample (+1). To be more picky :) I would change the `if (counter == 9)`
 to `if (counter >= colours.length)`

Comment: @Boro : Thankyou and KEEP SMILING :-), though what you said regarding condition is one better approach then mine, though regarding `JPanel` having default `Opaque` property, this might not be right always, have a look at this statement taken from [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/problems.html) which states **"Make sure your component is opaque. JPanels, for example, are opaque by default in many but not all look and feels."**

Comment: Good one - well defended. Didn't know that truth about `JPanel`s before. Thanks for teaching me - always happy to learn more. Oi :)