# How to stop the execution with a stop Button?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I am creating a program that is sending data from logfiles to a database. The programm should start when I hit a run Button, and stop when I hit a stop button. Until now, I was able to make it run when I hit the Run Button, but haven't been able to stop it. Can someone help me?

The Programm that I want to stop is this(I don't think that all of it is important in order to do the stopping, but I'll put the whole programm):

```
private void RunActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    // Creating a Timer object and scheduling the program to run every ten minutes
    if(evt.getSource() == Run) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // THE CODE, WITH WHAT HAS TO BE DONE
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);;
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);;
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);;
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);;
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);;
                }
            }
        }, 0, 60 * 1000 * 10); //Number of minutes, until the program starts to run again
    }
}                                   

private void StopActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

So what should I do to stop it? Thanks in advance

Comment: My lord that is a wall of code. Please cut it down to only what is *absolutely necessary*.

Comment: you can use Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

Comment: I updated the code, because from what I read, I need to make something when I declare the methods, but I don't know what, and where to put it..

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15676695/1057230), might be able to give some idea in the said directtion, I HOPE :-)

Comment: @HoryHene : This thread related to [Swing Timer's basic functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11037231/1057230), might can help you too, Please do have a look :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unlike C#, Java has not a "way to go" when it comes to async task cancelation. As I was in the need for a cancellable Task as well, I adapted the beautiful [Cancel-Token pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx) from .NET:

Your task (MyAsyncTask) must inherit from [CancelableTask](https://github.com/IsNull/archimedesJ/blob/master/src/archimedesJ/threading/CancelableTask.java) and overwrite the abstract method

```
public abstract T runCancelable(CancellationToken token) throws OperationCanceledException;
```

Put there your async running code - and periodically check the [CancellationToken](https://github.com/IsNull/archimedesJ/blob/master/src/archimedesJ/threading/CancellationTokenSource.java#L75)'s method **isCancellationRequested**(). If this returns true, return. (You have a clean cancel handling this way)

So running your cancelable task goes like this: ([ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html))

```
CancellationTokenSource cancelSrc = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancelableTask<Object> task = new MyAsyncTask(cancelSrc.getToken());
//since CancelableTask is a Runnable, you can pass it to any ExecutorService
executor.execute(task);
```

Now, to cancel your task, you can use the CancellationTokenSource:

```
cancelSrc.cancel();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very graceful, but simple : use a boolean :

```
 public void run() {
   if (go) {
     //...
   }
 }
}                                   

private void StopActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
 go = false
}
```

And add 'go = true' in actionPerformed of start button

Comment: Split the DB operation into small chunks (if possible) and check the stop boolean between chunks.

Comment: @rossum: In most cases not feasible. It will be hell of a job if at all possible.

Comment: So it will be a hell of a job...I understand know what my possibilities are..It's not a necessary thing to have in my program..but I wanted it to be more user friendly :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your program is struck with a blocking call like DB operation then there is no option other than killing db connection to come out of program. So if Db operation is on then Stop button cannot work.

In other cases simplest way will be to interrupt the thread by using "interrupt" function of Thread class on your stop method and then check for interrupt exception in your run method to gracefully exit.